# Adding custom data based attributes based on Response object

Tags: dropzone.js

Halo ! I'm trying to implement `dropzonejs` in a very specific way. Actually I follow the standard implementation described on the official page. Everything works perfectly.

But I'm willing to attach the server's generated URI for each uploaded file directly when uploaded : when uploading it's creating a database entry with some stuff like a page uri with title etc. This mean that the server would return as a response the `id` of the database saved file in order to attach the `href` attribute with its value to the the element in front.
This is quite ok to do this when only one file is uploaded, but it becomes trickier when bulk uploading.

So maybe I didn't understand the documentation well (and I'm quite sure I didn't), but is there any way to add custom `data-dz-like` attributes based on my server's response ? I'd like something like `data-dz-url` where the url points to a database entity (not the file itself).
Or if not if there is an "easy way" to handle this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

```
myDropzone.on('success', (file, response) => {
    file.previewElement.href = "/admin/media/"+response.id+"/show/"
})
```

`file` is reference to the current uploaded element. It's possible to extend it's html attributes through `previewElement`. Setting the `data-type` attribute in the template before, then assigning it the right value works aswell.

Hope this will help some.